# Start file php from shell

Tags: php, linux, shell

I guys, I need a very simple script, but I have no idea how to do.

I need a script to start a php file from a file shell.sh.

because I'd like to start a php file every 30 minutes!!  (chronetab)

thank you very much!

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: `php myfile.php`...?!

Comment: I'm using windows but I have to put the file in a shell that uses linux server online

Comment: be clear about what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following in the cron should do just what you need

```
*/30 * * * * /path/to/php -q /path/to/file.php
```

This goes on the linux web server.

Comment: wow! great! but I need simply a script in shell that start myphp.php

Comment: Why? by calling php -q /path/to/file.php from within the cron then it will execute the php file without the need for a script in shell.  That is just complicating things, if you need to pass any args to the php file you can do that within the cron as well.